# MSBuild ClickOnce error: "Deployment and application do not have matching security zones"

Tags: msbuild, clickonce

We're trying to publish a ClickOnce application through [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild). We've got it working fine for an installed version of the Windows application.

However, when we set install to false, so that it just runs the application from the web, we get the following error when we try to run the application from the URL: "Deployment and application do not have matching security zones" This works fine in Internet Explorer. We only get the error message in Chrome and FireFox.

Here is a sample of the project file settings.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SrcTreeRoot>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\..</SrcTreeRoot>
    <!--ClickOnceDeployFolder>$(WebOutputDir)\AnalyzerPC</ClickOnceDeployFolder-->
    <ProjectGuid>{8205E593-F400-41AE-8D6F-DEA290B2DCF9}</ProjectGuid>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ApplicationIcon>Graphics\EDA Icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <AssemblyName>DASHQueryBuilder</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>TetraData.Analyzer</RootNamespace>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>...</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
    <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
    <SignManifests>true</SignManifests>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <ManifestKeyFile>$(BuildDir)\Certificates\TetraDataCode.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
    <PublishUrl>http://localhost/DASHQueryBuilder/</PublishUrl>
    <Install>false</Install>
    <!--InstallFrom>Web</InstallFrom-->
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <PublisherName>Follett Software Company</PublisherName>
    <TrustUrlParameters>true</TrustUrlParameters>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>false</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(SrcTreeRoot)\Build\TaskInit.Tasks" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(SrcTreeRoot)\Build\TaskOverrides.Tasks" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Analyzer.csproj" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishDir>$(WebOutputDir)\DASH Query Builder\</PublishDir>
    <ApplicationVersion>$(MajorMinorVersion).0.0</ApplicationVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="BeforeResolveReferences">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\DASHQueryBuilder.config" DestinationFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\app.config" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Below  is Microsoft's answer to the thread I posted on their forum.  Basically they did support chrome back then, but now there is a plugin for Chrome [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eeifaoomkminpbeebjdmdojbhmagnncl) that works great.

> Hi fbanderson,
>
> I found an article talking about ClickOnce in Firefox.
>
> http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-deploying-clickonce-ie-firefox.aspx
>
> .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 offers a component called .NET Framework
>   Assistant 1.0 which handles ClickOnce .applications. If you have
>   installed that component, the dialog appear to you in FireFox should
>   contain a “Run ClickOnce application” button. Do you see that button
>   when you trying to launch the app?
>
> For Google Chrome, we don’t have experience for it. It is a new
>   browser and we lack test on it.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Kira Qian
>
> MSDN Subscriber Support in Forum
>
> If you have any feedback on our support, please contact
>   msdnmg@microsoft.com Please remember to mark the replies as answers if
>   they help and unmark them if they provide no help. Welcome to the

Comment: I still get this error on VS2013...These guys never learned. Can't believe how buggy VSTO is!!!!!!!!!!!1

Comment: The link in the answer is broken.  But you can search the webstore for 'clickonce' and find a number of options: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/clickonce I used Meta4 ClickOnce Launcher and it worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution that I'll be glad to share with you. You can do it with [MageUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or with Visual Studio. I am really delighted to use ClickOnce as my deployment now works both with Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Firefox.

## MageUI

If you use MageUI, you have to check `Include the provider URL in the Manifest` and type the associated URL of the web server.

## Visual Studio

If you use Microsoft Visual Studio, then on the <kbd>Publish</kbd> tab of the project properties, click on the <kbd>Updates...</kbd> button, then in the update location, type the URL of the publishing Web Server.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and other browsers may try to install clickonce apps from a downloaded version of myapp.application (without the rest of the payload). This causes havoc (with strange error messages) if you want the install to happen from a website. To ensure this works as intended you can do what is mentioned in this answer or, if using scripting with Mage, some variant of this command - dim deploymentCmd : deploymentCmd = chr(34) & mageExePath & chr(34) & " -New Deployment -Name " & chr(34) & "My Application" & chr(34) : deploymentCmd = deploymentCmd & " -ProviderURL [full url]myapp.application -IncludeProviderURL true"...

Comment: (This was a failed attempt to add some clarity by adding a similar comment to the two answers that helped me partially but this one got edited out as a separate answer. The answer by Backouche is essentially correct (hence the 7 upvotes) but it doesn't cover the cmdline Mage version or include detail about why it is might actually be applicable...)